# Horizontal Scaling a JSF 2.3 Application

Tags: session, jsf, horizontal-scaling

I have a WebApp developed using JSF2.3 with Primefaces 7.0. As per the requirement, I have to make it compatible with horizontal scaling.

I have googled around and found some of the sources:

[Horizontal scaling of JSF 2.0 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166883/horizontal-scaling-of-jsf-2-0-application)

(From this question, I'm really interested to know these 2 points:

- Instruct JSF (via configuration) to store its state on an external
  resource (e.g. another server running a very fast in-memory
  database), then access that resource from the JSF servers when
  application state is needed?

**Question**: is this possible?

- Instruct JSF (via configuration) to be stateless?

**Question**: is this possible?
)

and

[Why JSF saves the state of UI components on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474316/why-jsf-saves-the-state-of-ui-components-on-server)

along with

https://auth0.com/blog/horizontal-scaling-jsf-applications-with-spring-session/

(but I really don't want to use Spring Session unless there is no other way)

Just help me to understand how can I achieve this?

Comment: What about Just using a Java ee server with clustering

Comment: I'm try to use WildFly 18 with HazelCast for clustering.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to turn on session replication for embedded tomcat servers in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774864/is-it-possible-to-turn-on-session-replication-for-embedded-tomcat-servers-in-spr)